# Как записать делители каждого числа в массив?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть задача разложить числа от a до b на делители. Эти делители нужно записать в массив, который будет частью другого массива. 
Вот этот код просто добавляет кучу делителей разных чисел. Мне же нужно, чтобы делители каждого числа были в отдельном массиве, чтобы дальше с ними можно было работать.

```
function devide(x) {
    for (let a = 1; a <= x; a++) {
        if (x % a == 0) {
            divisors.push([a])
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getDivisorsRange(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
        var temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    result = new Array();
    var index = 0;
    for (let i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        result.push({
            num: i,
            divisors: new Array(),
        })
        for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                result[index].divisors.push(j);
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
    return result;
}

getDivisorsRange(25, 40);
```

И ещё. Функцию поиска делителей лучше чуть-чуть оптимизировать, а именно - сделать цикл не до самого числа, а до корня и, при нахождении делителя, вставлять в массив divisors не только само число, но и то число, которого не хватает для получения числа, для которого мы ищем делитель (если только это не квадратный корень из этого числа)

P.S. как то так:

```
    for (let j = 1; j <= forto; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            result[index].divisors.push(j);
            if (j * j != i) {
                result[index].divisors.push(i / j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Классный способ. Спасибо!